# ¿Son preferibles las llamadas al sistema bloqueantes o las no bloqueantes?

Tags: linux

Sobre las llamadas al sistema bloqueantes y no bloqueantes, ¿cuáles son preferibles? ¿Cuáles se utilizan más?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende de que quieras hacer, estilos de programación, paradigmas, etc.

Las llamadas blocking, son las que (simplificando), esperan y "bloquean"(valga la redundancia) el hilo/proceso en el que se ejecutan. Todos los ejemplos que me vienen a la cabeza ahora mismo tienen que ver con IO pero de seguro debe haber alguno que haga otra cosa.

Generalmente utilizas llamadas "bloqueantes" cuando la aplicación no va a ejecutar varias tareas a la vez o cuando las tareas necesitan esperar (sincronizarse) por eventos o datos externos. Ahora, esto tampoco es tan rígido, puedes tener un sistema haciendo blocking IO en un hilo y calculando los dígitos de `PI` en el otro y aunque estás utilizando `read` (que bloquea el hilo) el programa no se te "cuelga".

Las llamadas asíncronas, non blocking o como te las encuentres en la literatura utilizan otra filosofía. Basicamente tu aplicación sigue haciendo sus cosas hasta que los recursos necesarios para la llamada estén disponibles y entonces el kernel (de nuevo, estoy pensando en `epoll` que es de entrada y salida) notifica que todo está listo y ejecuta la llamada. En este paradigma se estila mucho los *callbacks* y los reactores (reactors) o bucles de IO.

Resumiendo, no hay "mejor" o "peor", hay "lo correcto para cada caso" (e incluso "lo que menos trabajo le lleve al programador")